# Button won't hide in p5 javascript

Tags: javascript, button, p5.js

I'm having an issue trying to hide a button I've created with `p5.js`:

```
var quit_button;
var pause = false;

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == '80') { // If p is pressed on the keyboard
    if (pause === true) {
      quit_button.hide()
      pause = false;
    } else {
      pause = true;
    }
  }
}

function restart() {
  quit_button.hide() // This isn't working
  pause = false;
  setup()
}

function setup() { //Start-up screen
  createCanvas(600, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background('#fae'); //This creates a new canvas
  if (pause === true) {
      quit_button = createButton('quit')
      quit_button.position(300,200)
      quit_button.mousePressed(restart)
      text("Game has been paused. Press P to resume.", 100, 100)
    } else {
    }
}
```

When I run the code and press `p` to pause my snake game, the game pauses (as expected). However, if I press `p` to unpause or if I click 'quit', the `quit` button is still there.

Comment: The `clear()` function only *clears* canvas content, it does not clear the DOM. The button should be hidden manually.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] (note that this should not be your whole program, but just enough for us to see the problem). Can you verify that the `if` statements are executing the way you think they are?

Comment: @WEB_UI I am aware of this. I have used `clear()` to clear the text, but the `quit_button.hide()` isn't doing its job

Comment: @WEB_UI Please note that this is a [tag:p5.js] question, and note the `quit_button.hide();` line.

Comment: Well you can **try** it without the extra built-in p5 function, just to make sure it's the `.hide()` function's fault, and know where your problem's at. Are you sure p5.dom.js is loaded in your code somewhere?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Sorry that took a while, all done

Comment: @WEB_UI I am sure. I have another button in my code that works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the game is paused, you're creating a new button every single frame. That's 60 buttons per second. So you have a bunch of buttons just sitting on top of each other. To see what I mean, right-click your button and click `inspect element` and look at all the buttons on your page.

So you need to make sure you only ever create one button. You can do this by checking whether `quit_button` has already been initialized, and if it has then skip the creation step:

```
if(!quit_button){
  quit_button = createButton('quit')
}
```

You could also move this creation code to the beginning and then have it hidden by default.